# Retrieve rows in HBase with unique substring

Tags: hbase

I need to group the rows in an HBase database based on a substring in the values of a particular column.

The values in that column are formatted like this:

```
[text1]_[text2]_[text3]
```

Example:

```
row1: abc_aaa_ababab
row2: abc_aaa_cdcdcd  
row3: abc_bbb_fgfgfg  
row4: def_ccc_ababab  
row5: hij_ccc_jkjkjk
```

How do I list all the possible values of [text2] (e.g. aaa, bbb and ccc)?

It is not necessary for me to retrieve all columns for each row in one go. The user is presented with the various [text2]s and when he selects "bbb", then only the rows with "bbb" are retrieved. I am thinking that I can use a FuzzyRowFilter to do the latter part.

But I am unsure of how to list the values of [text2]. Can it be done by using an existing filter, perhaps a custom filter or a different approach?

Note: The database schema is created by a customer - changing it is possible, but a cumbersome process. So suggestions on redesigning the schema are valuable but secondary compared to using the outlined schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this schema will be highly inefficient as you'd need  full table scan for each search.

I'd add a table with mapping of all possible sub-strings to row ids